# SQL Server, IN operator show different results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working on SQL server,i was trying to count the total number of rows based on some criteria as shown in the simple query bellow:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM my_table WHERE (supp=92 OR (supp=94 and organisation <> 'LDF'))
```

knowing that my_table do not contain any rows with `supp=92` and `organisation='LDF'` i decided to make the query simpler like the following:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM my_table WHERE supp IN (92,94) and organisation <> 'LDF'
```

The results of the two queries were totally different.

Yet the queries look totally the same for me, i've been trying to figure out where the problem is, but i couldn't find an answer.

it's really confusing to me, thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Consider a row where supp = 92 AND organisation = 'LDF'. It is included in the first query, but excluded from the second.

Comment: Also consider a row where supp = 92 AND organisation IS NULL.  It would be included in the first query, but excluded from the second.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but a row where supp=92 and organisation='LDF' do not exist on my_table, thats why this is really confusing

Comment: thank you @AHiggins, that was the case, with the NULL values in the organisation field, i didn't knew the operator <> excludes the null values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `organisation` column contained any `NULL` values where `supp=92`, the first query would return them but the second query would exclude them.  This is because this code:

```
organisation <> 'LDF'
```

would return 'NULL', not 'TRUE', if the organisation field is NULL.

I'd recommend you read Robert Shelden's excellent article on all the ways that NULL can trip you up; the entire article is worth reading, but [the ninth point](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-nulls-horribly-wrong-in-sql-server/#ninth) talks about this specific scenario.

Comment: That's it, thank you, i didn't knew the operator <> excludes the null values

Comment: Happy to help! I've updated my answer with a link to a really good article that dives deeper into this topic.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same

First:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM my_table 
WHERE supp=92 
   OR (supp=94 AND organisation <> 'LDF')
```

Second is equivalent to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM my_table 
WHERE (supp = 92 OR supp = 94) 
  AND organisation <> 'LDF'
```